# Waiting for thread to finish without blocking UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Im running a Thread inside methode and i want to return a value once the thread finish, the problem that i tried to do join() but that blocks the UI thread.
How could i wait for the thread to finish and then return the value without blocking the UI thread ?

```
Boolean foo(){

myThread mt = new myThread();
mt.start();     
return mt.isSentSuccessfully;

}
```

Comment: Providing some code may help.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't turn this round and make the background thread signal to the UI when it's completed? (This would be the normal way of doing things, thus avoiding polling.)

Comment: can you explain more or provide a code snippet of how this could be done. thanks

Comment: Your example suggests that you don't need a thread to do the work.  If you are waiting on the thread to complete, there's no reason to spawn off a new thread at all.  It slows the whole process down, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Android's `AsyncTask` for that.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
When I use it, I put the background task in a class that extends `AsyncTask` and overwrite the `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute(..)` methods to show/hide the `ProgressDialog`.  It works quite nicely.

Comment: i already take a look at it but i dont think its the best fit what im trying to do, how could i wait for it to finish and then return the value inside the calling methode?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. You say that you don't want to block the UI but you want the calling method (likely from the current Activity) to call a long-running method and wait for it to return. You may be able to have the long-running thread invoke an Activity when it is done its job.

Comment: @Fevos: what value can you return from method if you don't block until other thread completes? The only way to do this is not to call your method in UI thread at all, offloading work to background thread... which is exactly what AsyncTask does.

Comment: @Fevos: What you want is impossible and unnecessary.

Comment: ill tell you why its necessary, i need other developer to use my class  and be able to call the methode and get the response back, if its not possible then i could look to other solution but i dont think its unnecessary!

Comment: It is the responsibility of the other developers to put your class in the background.  They can write a wrapper that extends AsyncTask and calls your class's methods.  You can't provide a class that will automatically do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to use the AsyncTask, then you might like to define a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

then in your background thread send a message to the main thread when the background job finishes with something like:

```
ActivityMainThreadClassName.this.myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
```

where myUpdateHandler is the handler you created.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try polling `Thread.getState()`?

Something like this:

```
android.os.Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
public void run () {
      if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
           // your code here
           return;
      }
      h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

This sample should poll a thread state every second... (*I didn't tested it*)